Github PR: Approval needed after approval has already been given?
I approved a PR, and see:
"approved these changes now"
but then right below that I still see:
"At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access."
I went to the branch, and I am a contributor, so I should have write access, right?
Not sure what's up with this PR.
I've approved the PR multiple times now. I've clicked the "Viewed" checkbox on all the files, but still it will not allow the Review required block to turn from the red X to the green circle white checkmark.

What rules are imposed on PRs in your repository? Also, are you qualified as a reviewer with write access? Sharing the repository can help.

Hey Jason! are there any codeowner rules? it usually defined in .github/CODEOWNERS file in your repo if they do. Do you see a shield icon next to some of the changed files' names? please add a screenshot of the PR status checks so we can at least see what you see :-) if it's a public repo, you can just paste the url as well

@tomerpacific yes, that is what is so boggling about this. I have reviewed many PRs for this repo. It's an internal repo, so I can't share it.

@Thatkookooguy we do not have a .github/CODEOWNERS, file. No shields on the files.
After this last try for an approval, I noticed "The merge-base changed after approval." and that lead me to: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/58535 which I need to read through.

Per the comment above, when I came back to this thread:
https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/58535?sort=top#discussioncomment-6233887
I was able to validate what @dgokcin verified. I closed the PR, reopened, resubmitted my same review, and this time it went through.
Might just mark this question as a dupe. My apologies for not finding the thread above sooner.

Sorry for the delay. I prepared my answer yesterday, but forgot to post it today.

As per the discusion you mention, check that the branch protection rules are not causing the issue: for instance, look for the rule that dismisses stale approvals when new commits are pushed.

Check also the branch protection rules for the target branch of your PR.
If "Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed" is enabled, try and disable it to see if this resolves the issue.
From that same discussion, if the merge-base has changed after your approval (i.e. if new commits are made to the base branch of the PR), GitHub may dismiss the approval.
Try closing and reopening the PR, as this action has been reported to temporarily resolve the issue.
